# Vídeo rodando no background

Tags: html, css

Boa Tarde galera!

Estou tentando fazer um código aqui de teste com um vídeo rodando em background, mas por algum motivo tem hora que funciona e tem hora que não. Se atualizar, vai Às vezes... Estou bem confuso.

Fiz no [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ledones/pen/GLPmmy), então se puderem me dar uma ajuda aqui...

Abraços

Comment: Ja utilizei esse plugin uma vez [YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer), funcionou muito bem!

Comment: Tenta colar seu código aqui no W3 eu fiz isso e funcionou ... mas se salvar pra compartilhar o autoplay não funciona deve ser bloqueado . Cole o código no lugar do original e aperte RUN...https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_autoplay

Comment: MBoss, projeto incrível esse! Incrível! Curti!

Comment: Denis, no W3 funcionou... A primeira vez. Na segunda vez que abri, não! Será algo com o arquivo de vídeo? Tem que estar codificado de forma diferente?
w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3FIFG2U2BM9

Comment: Testa no seu servidor local pois acho que essas plataformas de códigos pode bloquear o auto play.

Comment: Tanto no site, quanto nas plataformas, quanto no local, tudo fica na mesma. Trava às vezes, às vezes vai... Loucura haha

Comment: Li um artigo por aqui e acho que entendi o que se passa. O arquivo de vídeo contém a faixa de áudio, mesmo sendo silêncio. Removi a faixa e agora está rodando legal. Os navegadores desde abril do ano passado tem a política de desativar o autoplay, caso o vídeo contenha faixa de áudio. Explicado, acho! haha

Comment: Nossa dessa eu não sabia valeu pela explicação! Se for video do Youtube pode né ! entendi..

Comment: E  é só no Chrome pelo jeito pois no Firefox funciona !

Comment: O artigo é real, e está dentro do site do Google Chrome, porém, aqui parou de funcionar usando esse esquema também. Então... Insano! hahaha

Comment: Tá certo que isso evitará abusos pois tem página com player escondido ai já é abuso mesmo. Mas imagina as web radios e afins!

Comment: Eu trabalho em uma rádio. Hoje em dia não tem mais a história de entrar na página e já ter som. Ou usa iframe ou outra página que a pessoa precisa entrar para ouvir a rádio. Som direto quando abre a página acho inconveniente total! hahaha